# New missing/unsatisfied dependencies: service jboss.ra.activemq-ra (missing) dependents

Tags: java, jboss7.x, activemq-classic, ejb-3.1, jboss-mdb

I followed this [link](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/IntegrationOfJBossAS7WithActiveMQ) and integrate ActiveMq 5.6 with JBoss eap 6.3. I am trying to use an MDB in my poc project. Though the war deployed successfull, onMessage() method doesn't get fired.

QueueName: employee_q

MDB,

```
package com.test.oms.mdb;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.ResourceAdapter;
import com.test.oms.entity.Employee;

@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue.employee_q") })
@ResourceAdapter("activemq-ra.rar")
public class QueueListener implements MessageListener {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(QueueListener.class
            .toString());

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message rcvMessage) {
        LOGGER.info("____________OnMessage fired______________");
        Employee emp = null;

        if (rcvMessage instanceof Employee) {
            emp = (Employee) rcvMessage;
            LOGGER.info("Received Employee instance: " + emp.toString());
        } else {
            LOGGER.warning("Message of wrong type: "
                    + rcvMessage.getClass().getName());
        }

    }
}
```

But when deploying this as OMS_POC.war I get the following output in jboss console and the report says `New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:...` problem

```
15:42:31,006 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS018559: Deployed "OMS_POC_1.war" (runtime-name : "OMS_POC_1.war")
15:42:31,007 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS018559: Deployed "activemq-rar.rar" (runtime-name : "activemq-rar.rar")
15:42:31,009 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.ra.activemq-ra (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."OMS_POC_1.war".component.QueueListener.CREATE]

15:42:31,029 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
15:42:31,030 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
15:42:31,031 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) started (with errors) in 11297ms - Started
312 of 358 services (8 services failed or missing dependencies, 74 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

These are the maven dependencies I am using,

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0.Final-redhat-19</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb3</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0.CR1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this is the standalone-full.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.6">

    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        ....
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
    </extensions>


    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                    <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization>
                    <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <audit-log>
            <formatters>
                <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
            </formatters>
            <handlers>
                <file-handler name="file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </handlers>
            <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="file"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
        </audit-log>
        <management-interfaces>
            <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
            </native-interface>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
        <access-control provider="simple">
            <role-mapping>
                <role name="SuperUser">
                    <include>
                        <user name="$local"/>
                    </include>
                </role>
            </role-mapping>
        </access-control>
    </management>

    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.4">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:cmp:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.2">
            <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
            <jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true</jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>
            <annotation-property-replacement>false</annotation-property-replacement>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.4">
            <session-bean>
                <stateless>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                </stateless>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple"/>
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
            </session-bean>
            <mdb>
                <!--resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:hornetq-ra}"/-->
                <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="activemq-ra.rar"/>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </mdb>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
            <caches>
                <cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/>
                <cache name="passivating" passivation-store-ref="file" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache"/>
            </caches>
            <passivation-stores>
                <file-passivation-store name="file"/>
            </passivation-stores>
            <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default">
                <data-store path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </timer-service>
            <remote connector-ref="remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="10"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
            <iiop enable-by-default="false" use-qualified-name="false"/>
            <default-security-domain value="other"/>
            <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.5">
            <cache-container name="web" aliases="standard-session-cache" default-cache="local-web" module="org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan">
                <local-cache name="local-web" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jacorb:1.4">
            <orb socket-binding="jacorb" ssl-socket-binding="jacorb-ssl">
                <initializers security="identity" transactions="spec"/>
            </orb>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxr:1.1">
            <connection-factory jndi-name="java:jboss/jaxr/ConnectionFactory"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
            <cached-connection-manager/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
            <expose-resolved-model/>
            <expose-expression-model/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
            <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsr77:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.1">
            <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
            </mail-session>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.4">
            <hornetq-server>
                <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
                <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>
                <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

                <connectors>
                    <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                    <netty-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                        <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    </netty-connector>
                    <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                </connectors>

                <acceptors>
                    <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                    <netty-acceptor name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                        <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                        <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                    </netty-acceptor>
                    <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                </acceptors>

                <security-settings>
                    <security-setting match="#">
                        <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                        <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                    </security-setting>
                </security-settings>

                <address-settings>
                    <address-setting match="#">
                        <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                        <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                        <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
                        <page-size-bytes>2097152</page-size-bytes>
                        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                    </address-setting>
                </address-settings>

                <jms-connection-factories>
                    <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                        </entries>
                    </connection-factory>
                    <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                        </entries>
                    </connection-factory>
                    <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                        <transaction mode="xa"/>
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                        </entries>
                    </pooled-connection-factory>
                </jms-connection-factories>

                <jms-destinations>
                    <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue">
                        <entry name="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                    </jms-queue>
                    <jms-queue name="DLQ">
                        <entry name="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
                    </jms-queue>
                    <jms-queue name="employee_q">
                        <entry name="java:/jms/queue/employee_q"/>
                    </jms-queue>
                </jms-destinations>
            </hornetq-server>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.4">
            <remote-naming/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1">
            <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.5">
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid/>
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
            <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
            <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
            <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
            <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1">
            <resource-adapters>
                <resource-adapter id="activemq-ra.rar">
                    <archive>
                        activemq-ra.rar
                    </archive>
                    <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                    <config-property name="ServerUrl">
                        tcp://localhost:61616
                    </config-property>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/activemq/ConnectionFactory" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ActiveMQConnectionFactoryPool" use-ccm="true">
                            <xa-pool>
                                <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                                <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                            </xa-pool>
                        </connection-definition>
                    </connection-definitions>
                    <admin-objects>
                        <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:/activemq/queue_out" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ActiveMQQueue.queue_out">
                            <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                                queue.queue_out
                            </config-property>
                        </admin-object>
                        <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:/jms/queue/employee_q" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ActiveMQQueue.employee_q">
                            <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                                queue.employee_q
                            </config-property>
                        </admin-object>
                    </admin-objects>
                </resource-adapter>
            </resource-adapters>
        </subsystem>
    </profile>

    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
        <socket-binding name="jacorb" interface="unsecure" port="3528"/>
        <socket-binding name="jacorb-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529"/>
        <socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445"/>
        <socket-binding name="messaging-group" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.messaging.group.address:231.7.7.7}" multicast-port="${jboss.messaging.group.port:9876}"/>
        <socket-binding name="messaging-throughput" port="5455"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>

</server>
```

UPDATE: `New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:...` message comes with @ResourceAdapter("activemq-ra.rar") when I comment this out server starts well but MDB doesn't work. Therefore I think the problem exists in activemq-ra.